# asp.net core + ef6 + mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use EntityFramework 6 with Asp.Net Core to interact with a mysql database.

I am having a really hard time trying to configure Entity Framework using code only, without all the configuration from `Web.config` that can be used in "classic" .NET MVC projects.

I am stuck with a timeout while trying to connect to the database (something I can achieve in another API which relies on `Web.config`, so it is definitely not a network issue).

I am currently instantiating my DataContext with a connectionString that is defined in my `appsettings.json` file:

```
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=db.example.com;Database=dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=123123;"
    }
  },
```

Then, in my `Startup.cs`:

```
        var connectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
        services.AddScoped((_) => new DataContext(connectionString));
```

Also, in `DataContext.cs`, I set custom configuration using the `DbConfigurationType` decorator:

```
public class CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public CodeConfig()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient",
            System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices());

    }
}
```

I am not 100% sure but I believe the problem is that I never tell EntityFramework that it is supposed to use the mysql provider, and I have absolutely no idea how I am supposed to do this.

This is the error I get and part of the stack:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, string accessToken, bool applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher<TInterceptor>.Dispatch<TTarget, TInterceptionContext>(TTarget target, Action<TTarget, TInterceptionContext> operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action<TInterceptor, TTarget, TInterceptionContext> executing, Action<TInterceptor, TTarget, TInterceptionContext> executed)
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices+<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> operation)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action<DbConnection> act)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable<int> commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, string createDatabaseScript)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable<int> commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(string targetMigration)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func<DbMigrationsConfiguration, DbContext, MigratorBase> createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction<TInput>.PerformAction(TInput input)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action<InternalContext> action)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TEntity>.Initialize()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TEntity>.get_InternalContext()
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<TResult>.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
Troco.ORM.Repository.UserRepository.GetUserInfoByLogin(string login) in UserRepository.cs
```

**-- UPDATE --**

After changing my configuration code to:

```
    public class CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
    {
        public CodeConfig()
        {
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory());
            SetProviderServices("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices());

        }
    }
```

It seems that now it tries to use the mysql provider. However, this error happens:

> NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for
>   provider factory of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory'.
>   Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the
>   application config.

Comment: Wondering if you installed the MySQL Connector/NET feature from the MySQL installer. The following documentation makes a quick reference about this if you are trying to go the non-web.config route in your ASPNET-Core project: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: @ajawad987 This did the trick. I can't thank you enough! I've been through that document countless times and I somehow missed that.
If anyone else is struggling with this, it is also important that your Connector/NET, your Mysql.Data and your Mysql.Data.Entity are all at the same version (which in my case is 6.10.8)

It is a shame however that you need to install another piece of software just because you can't configure it under `web.config`

Answer (score 2):

As @ajawad987 point out in his comment, it is necessary to download and install Mysql Connector/NET in order to get it working without the web.config file.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/